# Querying XML-fragment in SQL Server regardless of Xml tree depth

Tags: xml, xpath, sql-server-2012

I have some XML in Sql Server (column of type xml) looking somewhat like this

```
<TreeRoot>
  <Node id="12" name="name2">
    <Node id="54" name="name4654">
      <Node id="75" name="name0943>
        <Node id="58" name="dfd2">
        </Node>
      </Node>
      <Node id="43" name="543d32">
      </Node>
    </Node>
  </Node>
</TreeRoot>
```

I am trying to design a query over this XML that will give me a list of all Node Ids and Node names, like this:

```
Name     Id
-----------
name2    12
name4654 54
name0943 57
dfd2     58
543d32   43
```

I have a query already that does this - but it is hardcoded to the specific levels of the tree, which means that I need to update this query as I add nodes to the xml fragment.

Is there a way to construct an XPath query that will give me this list - and is robust enough to handle additional levels in the future?

Thanks,

:-)

/Jesper
Copenhagen, Denmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @XmlTable 
        (ID, XmlData)
VALUES
        (1, '<TreeRoot>
  <Node id="12" name="name2">
    <Node id="54" name="name4654">
      <Node id="75" name="name0943">
        <Node id="58" name="dfd2">
        </Node>
      </Node>
      <Node id="43" name="543d32">
      </Node>
    </Node>
  </Node>
</TreeRoot>')

SELECT
    NodeName = XC.value('@name', 'varchar(50)'),
    NodeID = XC.value('@id', 'int')
FROM @XmlTable
CROSS APPLY XmlData.nodes('//Node') AS XT(XC)
```

Gives me the output you're looking for.

Basically, the `.nodes()` will return a "virtual" table of XML fragments that correspond to the XPath expression in the call - and `//Node` will select all `<Node>` elements - regardless of where in the XML tree they live. Not sure if this is going to be super fast on large XML structures - but it should work.